# Testing for a 401 REST Response with Cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, rest-client

Question on how to check for a desired 401 REST response with Cucumber.

Items of note:
 - This is not a Rails app.
 - Cucumber version is 1.3.17
 - I'm using rest_client 1.7.3:  https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client
 - I have steps:

```
  When a GET request is made with no token
  Then status code should be '401'
```

And definitions:

```
  When /^a GET request is made with no token$/ do
    @response = RestClient.get "http://<hidden>"
  end
  Then /^status code should be '(\d+)'$/ do |code|
    expect(@response.code).to eq(code.to_i)
  end
```

The "Then" works fine for a '200' response, but I'm stopped from testing for a 401 because the run errors out on the "When" with, you guessed it, a 401 error.

I've searched all over the interwebs for suggestions.  I've tried the @allow-rescue tag before my scenario (which seems to be a RAILS thing - but I tried it anyway.)  I haven't found a way to do a 401 test.

Anyone have any ideas (other than looking at the failures in the test report and saying 'yup, those are supposed to fail'?)

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: Did you try to catch the exception and check that this is the good one ?

Comment: Could you give us the stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for responding Fabrice31 and Bruce Li.  Kyle was able to provide an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for RestClient: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rest-client/1.6.7/frames

You could either run it in a try/catch block:

```
begin
  RestClient.get 'http://example.com/resource'
rescue => e
  e.response
end
```

You can pass a parameter to the RestClient that will have it return the exception instead.

```
RestClient.get('http://example.com/resource'){|response, request, result| response }
```

Comment: Excellent Kyle!!  That works perfectly and allows me to test for the 401 specifically!  Thanks!!